# My profile picture pattern just changed automatically; how can I restore the old one?

Tags: support, profile-page, image

Title says it all.  My profile picture pattern just changed automatically:

[image]

I liked my old one better.  How can I restore it?

Documentation: My old has a 's=32':

https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8f797ea833cc6940de4268873d28c616?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG

[image]

while my new  has a 's=64':

https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8f797ea833cc6940de4268873d28c616?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG

[image]

Comment: My avatar completely changed too, today... It used to be white and blue, now it's white and purple with a different shape.

Comment: Related mother Meta post: [Why is my profile image different?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different).

Comment: @mosa Can you comment on exactly what happened here? It looks pretty buggy to me.

Comment: It happened to me last year where my gravatar changes to something completely different. Luckily, I coincidentally had a saved copy of the old one. What you see for my profile pic now is actually an image of the original gravatar, not my current default profile pic. Annoying, but it happens. Moral of story: try not to get too attached unless you back up the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got an email address associated with your account? [Usually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139071/) the stock profile picture (a.k.a. 'gravatar') is based on the [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of your email address, but if you haven't linked one to this account then it reverts to the hash of your IP address. In that case, if you want the old picture you need to re-log in from your old IP, save the picture, and put it in specifically as a custom pic.

---

Edit:

Since you do have an email address associated with your account, it looks like something has indeed changed behind the scenes, and the solution probably involves setting a custom profile pic if you can recover the old one. Googling your username reveals this pretty interesting result:

[image]

The old picture is still in the Google cache, but it's obviously pulling the new one now, so here it is for you before it disappears,

[image]

and that may be your best shot at it. (If it is, in fact, your old pic - I don't really know what it looked like.)

---

Also, here is @Qmechanic's in case s/he wants the old picture back:

[image]

The new one weirds me out, to be honest.

Comment: Unfortunately most ISPs don't have enough IPv4 addresses to go around, so most people (at least in the US) don't have static IPs. Logging in from the old one might be impossible. I wonder if the gravatar generator is public (and if there's a good way to find what IP address one used to have).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty:  I do have an e-mail address associated with this (and all the other SE communities to which I belong).  Same e-mail address I've had for over 10 years.  First logged into SE (the original [so]) in 2010.  Just today has my icon changed.

Comment: @pr1268 This looks like it's one for the SE team, then. It would help if you can clarify in the question exactly which sites the changes happened in.

Comment: @pr1268 See edit.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: Worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, @emilio for I was missing the classic Qmech ;( Most of us are now the victim of this epidemic...hmm.